# Remove .html/php extension

Tags: .htaccess

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiXpb.png)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

Why doesn't .htaccess work? I need it to upload it to my website (Tested on localserver).
httpd.conf AllowOverride is set on ALL

Comment: You've probably not set `AllowOverride` in the correct place. It's either not being processed at all, or another (more specific) directive is overriding it. (Presumably you have restarted Apache?) Where _exactly_ have you set the `AllowOverride` directive? It needs to be set in the most _specific_ `<Directory>` container in the appropriate `<VirtualHost>` (assuming you are using vHosts), or the main server config.

Comment: Instead of linking to an external screenshot, you need to include the relevant information in the body of your question (as text).